# Jquery: On DOM ready function in referenced js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In my view I have a reference to a JS file the I wrote. In that file I have only this code:

```
$(function () {
     alert('x');
});
```

why it's not being called while if I move that code into script tag inside the view it does being called?

Comment: You probably reference jQuery `.js` file after you reference that file, so it won't recognize `$(....)` stuff. Also please remove the MVC tag, unless it's somehow related in which case explain how it's related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the referenced js file is being loaded before you have loaded jQuery?  Or perhaps the js file is not being loaded at all?

Comment: You are right. there was something bad in the reference that VS generate for the js file... Thanks!